# Display loading dialog android while uploading file

Tags: android, url

I am uploading a file to my server using http post i have a simple method witch gets the job done but the loading...dialog never gets displayed how can i fix this ... here is my code

```
public void send_data() throws IOException
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CaptureTestActivity.this, "", 
        "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    dialog.show();

    String urlServer = "http://poi.gps.ro:80/postimg?lat=" + String.valueOf(mDraw.lat) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(mDraw.lon)+"&comment=" + tmp;
    Log.w("DHA", urlServer);
    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    if (url != null)
    {   
        Log.w("DHA", "Merge aici");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (connection != null)
        {
            Log.w("DHA", "Si aici mere!");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "poi.gps.ro");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=*****");
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + "PICT0000" +"\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.write(btarr.toByteArray());
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            Log.w("DHA", "Incep trimiterea pozei!");
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String conn = connection.getResponseMessage();
        //  InputStream in  = connection.getInputStream();
        //  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            Log.w("DHA", conn);
            Log.w("DHA", "Serverul a raspuns cu " + String.valueOf(serverResponseCode));
            if (serverResponseCode == 200)
            {
                AlertDialog alertDialog;
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Super :)");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Poza a fost trimisa cu success.");
                alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                         finish();

                    } }); 
                alertDialog.show();

            }


}
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: To display your `loading` dialog, you must do the actual file transfer on a different thread.  Use AsyncTask or Thread or Runnable for this.  You should not have any long-running process on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, you need an AsynTask, most practical option.  You can do some clever things with the *Void, Void, Void* part, but unless you want to look into the documentation, this should work fine.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

....

    private final class AsyncSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Sending Data");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait, data is sending");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            send_data(); // You probably have to try/catch this
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

And then when you call it, the cleanest way is to call

```
new AsyncSender().execute();
```

Also, I should mention, this should be an inner class, meaning don't create a separate java file for it. Generally I just stick them at the bottom of the class file I'm working in.

Comment: Hey opc0de, I should have been more clear.  Change "MyActivity.this" to the name of the java file you're in.  So if you're working in "MySendingActivity.java", then it would be "MySendingActivity.this".  It's just a clever way of getting the context.

Comment: This will only work if this class is inside of a class that extends an Activity, this giving it a context.  I've adjusted the example to show an outer class, hopefully that clears it up

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the UI with your upload code. You need to use an AsyncTask / thread / service.

[Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you call ProgressDialog.show() twice which is unnecessary. And perhaps one reason why it doesn't show is because it is dismissed right after it is shown.
For instance if your file upload is really fast or fails or is done in another thread the call to dismiss() will be called so quickly that you won't be able to ever see the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do any task in background and want to show another thing on screen the you should use **AsyncTask**...

This is an example of login using AsyncTask now u can update it...

```
public class mytask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    SoapObject request;
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground(Void... params");
        Object flag = null;
        try {
            flag = TAGS.sendToServerAndGetResponse(request, SOAP_ACTION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return flag;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if (result.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

            mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.setClass(PresenTABActivity.this,
                    presentation_list.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Enter Valid Username or Password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            edtPass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            edtUname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            chk_remeber_me.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Username", edtUname.getText().toString()
                .trim());
        request.addProperty("password", edtPass.getText().toString().trim());

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_login);
        loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_loading);
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        edtPass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        edtUname.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        chk_remeber_me.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this page: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Example

```
private class UploadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, title, message, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // Do your work .. uploading
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```